# Conditionally closing a tag in HAML

Tags: haml

I'm iterating through a set of items and displaying them in lists nested in divs. The goal is to have a div for each day and within each div show the items for that day.

How do I do this in HAML? I don't think I can (or should) conditionally close and create a new tag like I could in erb.

I tried:

```
- @items.each do |item|
  - if item date is diff from previous make a new container
    .container
      %h2 #{item.date}
      = yield_content :display_item item
  - else
    = yield_content :display_item item
```

But this creates the following:

```
<div class="container">
<h2>01/28/2012</h2>
      <ul>
            <li>
              ... item
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
        <li>
        ...item
      </li>
```

But I want the other item in the same div.
I'm using ruby, sinatra (including the content_for helper)

Comment: I think this is not possible in haml. You might want to change your data structure.

Comment: I'm gathering the data on the server side and it's already sorted by date. It seems silly that I should have to pass the view the following structure: [date => [items]]. If I can't get a solution that would be my fallback

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is to use more and better Ruby :)

```
- @items.group_by(&:date).each do |date,items|
  .container
    %h2= date
    - items.each do |item|
      = yield_content :display_item item
```

*See [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) docs for more details.*

You *could* [close and re-open the containers and headers as you were thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893538/how-do-i-close-the-container-div-in-a-loop/8951158#8951158), but this is a horrible, hard-to-maintain hack that I would suggest against. Embrace the elegance of Ruby and Haml; don't write Haml like it was ERB.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's as clean as I can get it. I was thinking of organizing it on the server side, but this reads cleaner to me and I don't think the perf would be affected.

Comment: So great -- that just cut out about a dozen lines of boilerplate.